# Cannot get remote client example application for Oracle Coherence working, can't connect to server

Tags: java, oracle-coherence

New to Oracle Coherence. I am trying to follow the example java remote client application in the Oracle documentation. I have two different computers each with a CentOS VM running on it. One VM is acting as the server and the other the remote client. I am trying to just run the sample TestClient integer application. I changed the configuration files so the server VM is set as the tcp-acceptor and the client looks for that remote address. The two VM's can ping each other

In the documentation when starting the cache server, why does it need the TestClient application on the classpath? Unlike the example I am not running both the server and client on the same machine, do I still need to do this? I have been starting up the cache server like so without the TestClient app on the classpath:

```
    java -cp COHERENCE_HOME\lib\coherence.jar;PATH_TO_CLIENT -Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=PATH\example-config.xml com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer
```

On the client side I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.tangosol.net.messaging.ConnectionException: could not establish a connection to one of the following addresses: [128.183.208.3:9099]; make sure the "remote-addresses" configuration element contains an address and port of a running TcpAcceptor
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.peer.initiator.TcpInitiator.openConnection(TcpInitiator.CDB:121)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.peer.Initiator.ensureConnection(Initiator.CDB:11)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.extend.remoteService.RemoteCacheService.openChannel(RemoteCacheService.CDB:7)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.extend.RemoteService.doStart(RemoteService.CDB:11)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.net.extend.RemoteService.start(RemoteService.CDB:5)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeService.startService(SafeService.CDB:53)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.safeService.SafeCacheService.startService(SafeCacheService.CDB:5)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeService.ensureRunningService(SafeService.CDB:27)
at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeService.start(SafeService.CDB:14)
at com.tangosol.net.ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory.startService(ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory.java:681)
at com.tangosol.net.ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory.ensureService(ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory.java:599)
at com.tangosol.coherence.config.scheme.AbstractCachingScheme.realizeCache(AbstractCachingScheme.java:50)
at com.tangosol.coherence.config.scheme.AbstractBundlingScheme.realizeCache(AbstractBundlingScheme.java:31)
at com.tangosol.net.ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory.ensureCache(ExtensibleConfigurableCacheFactory.java:254)
at com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.getCache(CacheFactory.java:205)
at com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.getCache(CacheFactory.java:182)
at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:11)
```

On the server side the cache server runs but I get:

```
2014-05-20 12:26:06.168/77.693 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.2.0.0 <Info> (thread=PacketListenerN, member=1): Scheduled senior member heartbeat is overdue; rejoining multicast group.
2014-05-20 12:26:06.185/77.710 Oracle Coherence GE 12.1.2.0.0 <Warning> (thread=PacketListenerN, member=1): MulticastUdpSocket failed to set receive buffer size to 16 packets (1MB); actual size is 11%, 1 packets (122KB). Consult your OS documentation regarding increasing the maximum socket buffer size. Proceeding with the actual value may cause sub-optimal performance.
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be super appreciated

Comment: Please post your configuration for all: server, proxy and client (local.config, pof.config, tangosol.override)

Comment: Did you try the Coherence Multicast test? http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Performing+a+Multicast+Connectivity+Test